# Real time Integer/Binary programming (microSecond compute time)

Tags: real-time, knapsack-problem, integer-programming

My binary programming problem is:

```
max: (a1 * x1) + (a2 * x2) + ..... + (an * xn)
```

subject to:

```
(c1 * x1) + (c2 * x2) + ..... + (cn * xn) < C

n = 10

a1, ... an, c1, ... cn, C are known

x1, ... xn are binary
```

This is a process task assignment problem. In my case, the overhead of solving the binary/integer programming problem needs to be very small (< 1 millisecond). When I run this with the CBC solver / lpsolve, it reports time of 2ms - 7ms. I dont have SCIP/Gurobi. Is there any way to solve this in less than a millisecond? Does it even seem to be reasonable to expect to solve this in less than a millisec?

(I did disable the printf's in CBC. But i am not sure if there are any other system operations that it is stuck with.... any log files it is writing)

Comment: Just a comment, but the big commercial solvers (Gurobi, CPLEX, Xpress) put their R&D effort into solving larger and harder problems - they may not be much better than the open/free solvers for very small instances. If you know that you have a specific problem structure you may be able to get a simpler implementation to run faster as it does not need to provide all the possible functionality that the general solvers provide. Think about restricting pre-solve, removing most or all cuts and heuristics unless they really help your problem, disabling any callbacks etc. Sort-of a RISC MIP solver.

Comment: Do you mean max? The solution to the above should always be the zero vector.

Comment: Thanks TimChippingtonDerrick for the response. After digging in more, i realized that this is the standard knapsack problem which can be solved efficiently using dynamic programming. The c++ implementation measures ~20us. I will post a reply with this.

Comment: hi Christopher, oops, yes that was supposed to be 'max'. Editing the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the standard knapsack problem which can be solved efficiently using dynamic programming. This has been discussed nicely in the [knapsack wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) (and also in mutiple stack overflow posts e.g. here [DP algo for knapsack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559674/dp-algorithm-for-bounded-knapsack?rq=1) and here [recursive knapsack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774769/how-do-i-solve-the-classic-knapsack-algorithm-recursively))

The c++ implementation measures ~20us on my core i7 @3Ghz